# find maximum in array using recursive functions

Tags: php, recursion

i wanted to find `max` in an `array` using `recursive` function what i found on internet is

```
            function multimax( $id )
            {
                $max = $id[0];
                foreach($id as $value)
                {
                    if($value > $max) 
                    {
                        $max = $value;
                    }
                    else if(is_array($value))
                    {          
                        $subvalue = multimax($value);            

                        if( $subvalue > $max )          
                        {
                            $max = $subvalue;
                        }
                    }

            }
            return $max;
```

where `$id` is array and `$max` is the maximum value .

it worked fine but i don't know how . can anyone please help understanding data flow

Comment: debug the code line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not that complicated

Check each of the values received if it's value is bigger than the current biggest,

If it is not a value but an array, recursively call itself again and test it again and then check the recursively received value if it is bigger than the one of the parent.

At the end, it returns the biggest value received

Meaning if you have an array with an inner array like: `[1 , 2 , [ 1 , 5 ] , 4]`

```
max: 0

1 < 2 => max = 2
  array:
    arraymax = 0
    0 < 1 => arraymax = 1
    1 < 5 => arraymax = 5
    return arraymax (5)
2 < 5 => max = 5
5 > 4 , do not change max
return Max (5)
```

I hope I could give you the desired answer

Answer (score 0):

Something simpler like

```
$data = array(1,3,5, array(-2,8,6), array(15,1,-27));
$result -INF;
array_walk_recursive(
    $data, 
    function ($value) use(&$result) {
        $result = max($value, $result);
    }
);
var_dump($result);
```

is a whole lot easier

Answer (score 0):

```
$max = $id[0];
```

//firt we store the firt value of the array as the max value,

```
foreach($id as $value)
```

//we loop the array

```
if($value > $max) 
{
     $max = $value;
}
```

// if the next value is heigher than the last value stored in $max then our max value is the $value,

```
else if(is_array($value))
{          
     $subvalue = multimax($value);            

     if( $subvalue > $max )          
     {
         $max = $subvalue;
     }
 }
```

// else if the $value is an array the we have to find the max in this array and store the max in $max by calling the same function,

and finally we return the max stored in the $max variable .

i hope this can explain somthing :)